# error C2062: type 'int' unexpected, unable to solve this error

Tags: c++

I am getting the following errors when i run my program

```
(61): warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
(63): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
(69): warning C4129: 'm' : unrecognized character escape sequence
```

Comment: In addition to the other errors, you *should* have gotten a warning for the call to `sqrt` with no declaration.  You need to add `#include <math.h>`.  You also need to figure out why your compiler didn't warn you about that.

Comment: The poor indentation of your code made it difficult to read.  I've corrected that.  I've also added comments to the lines flagged by the error and warning messages; that makes it a lot easier for readers to find the relevant lines without having to count.

Answer (score 3):

`\m` is not a recognised escape character is caused by:

```
printf("\max");
```

Change to:

```
printf("max"); // or "cout << "max";" as this is C++.
```

A `\` in a string literal is used to escape the following character, like `\n` for example.

`int` is a primitive datatype, not a class instance so `int.MaxValue;` is invalid. To get the maximum value for an `int` you would use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and `#include <limits>`, *but* the conversion error is caused by:

```
L += dist(R[i], R[i+1]);
```

because `L` is an `int` but `dist()` returns a `double`.

Change `L`, `min` and `max` to type `double` and use:

```
double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your warning is from here `L += dist(R[i], R[i+1]);`
L is an integer and you arre adding a double.
The error is from this line `int min = int.MaxValue;` and yes this is no valid c++.
I assume you want `int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();`
And the last warning is `printf("\max");

`\m` is not a known escape sequence..

Answer (score 2):

```
int min = int.MaxValue;
int max = 0;

if (L > max)
{
max = L;
printf("\max");
}
```

Change it to

```
int min = numeric_limits<int>::max();
int max = 0;

if (L > max)
{
max = L;
printf("%d\n", max);
}
```

Don't forget to

> ```
> #include <limits>
> ```

And you should to use
    "iostream"
not
    "cstdio"